# Adding Flutterwave in to django template and view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, flutterwave

I have created flutterwave developer account, as you can see down here I have setup everything except **template and views.py file**

settings.py file

```
FLUTTERWAVE_SECRET_KEY = 'my-keys'
FLUTTERWAVE_PUBLIC_KEY = 'my-keys'
```

Installed apps:

```
'djangoflutterwave'
```

urls.py file

```
path("djangoflutterwave/", include("djangoflutterwave.urls", namespace="djangoflutterwave"))
```

I don't know how to write the amount to charge for each user and also don't know what to put inside my template and views.py file.

Is anybody who wish to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the Readme of the library you are using from: https://github.com/bdelate/django-flutterwave

If you did in fact read the Readme, you would see it contains full instructions and usage examples which directly answer your question.